# perl library getopts.pl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to install a program, but keeps giving an error saying it doesn't find the perl library getopts.pl. My perl version is v5.16.2.

The error message is:

```
Can't locate getopts.pl in @INC (@INC contains:
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.2 
/usr/lib/perl5/5.16.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
/usr/lib/perl5/5.16.2 
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at ./sqc line 179.
```

Do you have any idea what is going on?
My platform is openSUSE version 12.3 (Dartmouth) (x86_64)

Comment: Perl libraries usually end with `*.pm`; anything that uses a `*.pl` as a library harkens back to the perl4 days (e.g. `require 'cgi-lib.pl'`). How old is this program?

Comment: In Debian, `getopts.pl` is in a package called `libperl4-corelibs-perl`. Perl 5 was released in 1994, making `getopts.pl` obsolete, so it's quite an antique.

Answer (score 8):

Why so complicate?

```
apt-get install libperl4-corelibs-perl
```

Comment: `get-apt`?  Really?

Comment: `yum install perl-Perl4-CoreLibs` on Centos

Answer (score 5):

`Getopt::Std` replaced `getopt.pl` -- you may find it in [`CPAN Perl4::CoreLibs`](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Perl4-CoreLibs-0.003/lib/Perl4/CoreLibs.pm)

try:

`cpan> install Perl4::CoreLibs`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the location you installed the `getopts.pl`,
e.g., `/home/lib/getopts.pl`. 
Make sure Perl can see the `getopts.pl` file
by doing the following in your script:

```perl
push(@INC, "/home/lib");
require "getopts.pl";
```

Should be good to go.